# How to remove button line in Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I used a spinner to display a list:

[image]

At the bottom of the list, there is this grey line. How i can remove it programatically??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only seems to appear on the HTC Evo, I'm not sure why it's there, but it's not something that I know of a work around for.  If you run the same app on another device it should be fine.  Hopefully this is something that will be fixed in an update.

Comment: This is a screenshot from the HTC desire.

Comment: Then maybe it's a problem with all HTC devices using the SenseUI.  I know that I had that problem on my HTC Evo, but not on my Sony Ericsson X10, Droid or G1.

Comment: Ok Thanks. But this is really annoying.